# What is the basis for Zapp Brannigan's uniform?

Tags: futurama

In the *Star Trek: The Next Generation* episodes "Encounter at Farpoint" and "Lonely Among Us", we see [guys in miniskirts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11355/what-is-this-man-doing-with-a-starfleet-mini-skirt):

[image: TNG guy in miniskirt]

Did those miniskirts inspire Zapp Branigan's outfit?

[image: Zapp Brannigan]

Comment: Do you have some screenshots you can add demonstrating this? I have no memory of them ever wearing skirts.

Comment: related: [What is this man doing with a Starfleet mini-skirt?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11355/what-is-this-man-doing-with-a-starfleet-mini-skirt)

Comment: Sorry, this is probably not a duplicate, after all. Ignore the VTC. @JackBNimble: See the other question above.

Comment: This was two separate questions, 1) What's with the skirt in Star Trek? and 2) Is Zapp Brannigan's uniform based on it? The former is definitely a duplicate. Revised it to only ask about Zapp Brannigan.

Comment: Thanks @MarkTrapp that's probably for the best.

Comment: I'm surprised nobody has suggested Roy Mustang yet...

Comment: The entire Futurama universe is loosely based around Star Trek's, such as Zapp apparently being what Kirk would be like if William Shatner was being himself, and the consistent hidden references to the ST universe.

Comment: They're not wearing skirts. To me it looks like a kind of tabard or tunic with a belt at the waist.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I always thought they were a shout-out to the outfit worn by classic comic book character *Magnus: Robot Fighter*. Right down to the white boots!

[image: Magnus: Robot Fighter 4 back cover]

[image: Magnus: Robot Fighter]

Comment: Those robots even resemble the robots from Futurama!

Answer (score 6):

The character Zapp Brannigan was based on *Star Trek*'s Starship captain James T. Kirk and the actor who plays him: William Shatner. He is also said to be based on comic book hero Flash Gordon. The idea of his uniform ***was*** to copy that of the women on the USS Enterprise (the *Star Trek* starship).

Comment: Do you have a reference that the costume wasn't a reference to the men?

Comment: @DavRob60 Uhura wasn't the only woman on the Enterprise. There was the nurse, and a number of enlisted or ensign women coming to Kirk for his <s>autograph</s> signature on (presumably) daily reports/orders/etc.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage There is a reference from the show's creators, but I can't find the link.

Answer (score 5):

The uniforms were drawn, or 'made', to resemble that of James T. Kirk in Star Trek (mostly Enterprise) but another reason is purely for the humour embedded in the sight of a grown man wearing a miniskirt.

Answer (score 0):

His not wearing pants is based on Magnus: Robot Fighter, but Zapp himself is based on James T. Kirk. However, the creators say he is based more on the actor, William Shatner, than on Kirk. Either way, that guy has swag!

Answer (score -6):

I suspect that the standard DOOP uniform isn't necessarily anything like what Zapp Brannigan chooses to wear. After all, he is a lecher, braggart, and narcissist.

[image: DOOP combat uniform]

This is obviously a combat uniform instead of a dress uniform, but captains of modern naval ships don't wear dress whites while on deck anyway. And the basic styles and cuts are the same, just finer cloths are used with more ornament (braids, brocades, etc).

Comment: Do you have any references that indicate what a standard DOOP uniform looks like?

Comment: Also we see in S1:Ep4 "Loves Labours Lost in Space" that Brannigan's men have essentially the same uniform as him.  Here is a link to a screenshot [LINK](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4114928/Photos/ZapsMen.png)